# SQL: Column value auto-decreases everyday?

Tags: sql

I have a table (named 'settings') containing 1 column (named 'days' (int)). I'm trying to figure out how it is possible for the days' value to automatically decrease every 24 hours.

For example:

```
At 10/12/2013 the value will be 20, 
at 11/12/2013 the value will be 19,
at 12/12/2013 the value will be 18...
```

Any tip is highly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need to store this as  opposed to calculating at run time? What happens when `0` is reached?

Comment: The database is connected to a VB.NET application. When 0 is reached, the application performs an action.

Answer (score 2):

If relating to SQL Server - it's not specified - you do need to schedule a daily task, either by using Sql Server Agent or a Scheduled Task in your os.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   CAST('30/12/2013' as date) - GETDATE() as [Days Remaining]
FROM
   Whatever_Table_You_Want
```

This might be a good 'view' or 'function' or 'stored procedure' -- but not sure why you'd want to store teh values in a table, as there is no dependence on a 'settings' (or any other) table for this kind of output.

If you do need to stored the values in a table for whatever reason, then you'd create a `job` for this at the server level to run an INSERT on your 'settings' table.